# Cannot find html and css file for Angular Dart component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am using Angular Dart version ^1.1.2+2.  I have a custom Angular component I am using that has a dart file, html file, and css file.  When I run in Dartium, everything seems to work fine.  However, when I compile everything up and run it in Chrome or Firefox, I get these errors:

```
GET https://dartlang.org/lib/classes/Controller/PlaybackSignalProcessingController.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED html dart2js.dart:18457
GET https://dartlang.org/lib/classes/Controller/PlaybackSignalProcessingController.html net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED html dart2js.dart:18457
```

This is what the beginning of the .dart file looks like

```
@Component(
    selector: 'playbackProcessingController',
    templateUrl: 'PlaybackSignalProcessingController.html',
    cssUrl: 'PlaybackSignalProcessingController.css',
    useShadowDom: false)
class PlaybackSignalProcessingController extends MainController {
  PlaybackSignalProcessingController get playbackprocessingctrl => this;

  PlaybackSignalProcessingController(EventBus eb) : super(eb)  {
    print("Playback Signal Processing Controller Constructor");
  }
```

And I bind the PlaybackSignalProcessingController in the main.dart file.  I have also tried using '../lib/classes/Controller/PlaybackSignalProcessingController' for the templateUrl and cssUrl paths and get the same problem.  I'm not sure why it cannot find the html and css files.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can/should access to the file with something like `templateUrl: 'packages/my_app/.../PlaybackSignalProcessingController.html'`.